# mailchimp template mc:edit not showing images

Tags: php, css, templates, mailchimp, mandrill

Using mandrill and php integration.

## template

```
    <img mc:edit="images">   --- this doesnt work
    <div mc:edit="images"></div>  ---- this works
```

any thoughts, would prefer the img tag so we can resize the image as required..

any help is much appreciate

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because mc:edit should only be applied to containers: [mail chimp documentation](http://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/template-language/). Try giving an html element the css value of `background-image: url("myImage.png");` so you can always replace the image with a different size and it'll still apply.

You could also just use your own `id="myUniqueIdentifier"` on the element as well.